# Relative import error/maximum recursion depth exceeded with py2exe using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.4, py2exe

I am trying to create an .exe-file from a script using py2exe (WinPython 3.4.4 in Windows 7). In this script I am using different backends of the matplotlib package (Version 1.5.2). All of my attempts resulted with the error:

> ... name = self._resolve_name(name, package, level)
>     File "M:\Python\WinPython-32bit-3.4.4.4Qt5b1\python-3.4.4\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 213, in _resolve_name
>       raise ValueError('attempted relative import beyond top-level package')
>   ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

With other packages, that are on the same directory-level as matplotlib, there is no problem. I read all the posts concerning this topic, but couldn't find a solution yet (including pyinstaller). Can anybody help me?

"setup.py":

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import matplotlib

setup(console=['skript.py'],
options={
   "py2exe":{
             "packages":   ['matplotlib.pyplot','matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf'], # List of all the modules you want to import
            }
        },
data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles(),        
)
```

**UPDATE**
I now installed matplotlib version 2.0.0. I import the packages in my script with

```
from matplotlib import pyplot, dates
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
```

Running the script in spyder works well. The error message when using py2exe now changed to:

> File "M:\Python\WinPython-32bit-3.4.4.4Qt5b1\python-3.4.4\lib\site-packages\py2exe\hooks.py", line 291, in **getattr**
>       self.__finder.safe_import_hook(renamed, caller=self)
>   RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Answer (score 0):

I seems you use py2exe the wrong way.

You first need to have a sunning python script that you want to convert to exe, say you call it `script01.py`.

Then in `script01.py` do

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

And **then** you write a `setup.py` script to convert `sctipy01.py` to exe like this, in its most simple form:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['script01.py'])
```

Comment: That is exactly what i did and what works without using matplotlib. Running the script.py in spyder works as well (from matplotlib import pyplot, dates
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator). But when I use py2exe the compilation fails.